# Wp theme not working well as forgot to create child theme

Tags: themes

So I installed a new theme in February and never knew about child themes concept. i had made numerous changes to the themes in settings and also updated the theme a few times in this period. but all of a sudden now when i go to theme options and try to change anything and save settings, everything goes wrong and my website starts looking like some crap. 
i guess this has to do with not creating a child theme.
Can i correct my mistake here?
i have tried to wipe out all the settings completely from wordpress database so that i could reinstall the theme and create a child theme... but failed. Not able to wipe out the settings. everytime i reinstall the theme, the website starts looking all dirty.
Please help

Comment: Are you sure this is an issue with the theme? I'm not sure what you mean by 'looking all dirty' but it may be that your site was hacked? Perhaps posting some screenshots might help

Comment: i am sure the site was not hacked. because the site is working fine currently. but the issue is i cannot make any changes in theme options coz whenever i save theme options, whole color settings change to the basic one automatically. i restored it from previous backup but now not able to make changes in theme options.

Comment: and... as i said before, i have been making all the changes to the parent theme itself without any child theme for last two months.

Comment: Are these color settings part of the theme as well or is that custom code you've added?

Comment: these settings are part of the theme

Answer (score 2):

The good news is that the only time a Child Theme is required, is if you are making (or plan to make) changes to the actual files that drive the theme.

If all of your changes to the theme have been restricted to the Wordpress Customizer or some other Options Panel within the Wordpress admin, then you don't need to worry about a Child Theme (which sounds like the case for you, from what you described).

Likewise, applying updates to the theme through the Wordpress Updates functionality should not break things either (with one potential caveat - if the theme author makes some mistakes).

If you're suddenly having issues with your site look and feel in the event of the latter situation (just making config changes via the WP admin tools), then the likelihood is that the issue is one of the following:

- The theme creator made some mistakes with their latest theme update(s), which is causing the issues.  If this is the case, you should reach out to the theme owner and see if they can provide help.  Where you do that will depend on where you got the theme (e.g. Wordpress.org vs. some purchased / premium theme site).
- You have one or more plugins on your site that are not working correctly, or that are conflicting with your theme.  This can happen if a plugin in question was written by someone who doesn't understand how to write their code in such a way that it will not conflict with other items.  You can quickly test this by disabling your plugins (either all of them at once, or one at a time - which takes longer), and see if your theme continues to be broken.
- Lastly, as one other poster mentioned, it is possible that your Wordpress site has been hacked or otherwise maliciously modified - which could break the theme's ability to handle configuration changes. If you think this might be the case, then the first step is to make a backup of your website, and I'd suggest downloading the backup to your local computer, just to be safe.  You can use a tool like UpdraftPlus (free version available in Wordpress Plugins) or something similar to create the backup, if your hosting provider doesn't already provide you a way to do that.

Then I'd suggest you do a quick security scan of your website using Sucuri SiteCheck (https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/), to see if there's any obvious signs of site abuse.  After that, I'd also suggest looking into a security plugin, to help protect your site from future abuse (e.g. You can search Wordpress Plugins for Wordfence, iThemes Security, or something else similar - there are plenty of options).

FWIW,
twykr.

Comment: thank you for an elaborate reply. will try to apply these and see if it works

Comment: Can you help me to completely wipe out the theme along with its settings and anything saved in the database related to it

Comment: Solved. It was a plugin issue. Cheers

Comment: Hey @kshitijkuldeep - to "wipe out the theme and it's settings" can be tricky, depending on how the theme creator wrote the code (some themes clean up after themselves when uninstalled, others leave their settings behind).

The fastest way to test the theme itself, would be to simply switch to an alternate theme (e.g. twenty-seventeen), and see if the issues persist.

Answer (score 0):

If your current theme doesn't have child even then there is no chance of this type of issues.

For the sake just make child theme go to dashboard  appearenc themes and activate child theme to see if your problem is solved.

If not there must be some theme issue .
Kindly be more specific about then.

Comment: it is definitely a theme issue. but dont know what

Comment: Does looking dirty means CSS issues, if yes then copy main theme CSS to child theme CSS . So that even if you update any plugin or WordPress theme in future you don't have to bother about CSS override issue. You can do one more thing go to plugin folder and comment extra plugins folder  and simultaneously check after commenting that does your site works as accepted because​ once it helps me to  find out the issue in my custom plugin.   You have to do this  hit and try methods only .No exact solution. Sorry for that

Comment: Solved. It was a plugin issue. Cheers